# inserting multiples values in sqlite

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I am working on iphone application in which i have to insert multiples values in table.
I am using the following code but getting the syntax error. Where is my syntax wrong?

```
INSERT INTO `ark1` (`A`, `B`, `C`) VALUES
('IKE', 'BEFÄLHAVARE OCH MILITÄRER', ' USA'),
('LEE', 'BEFÄLHAVARE OCH MILITÄRER', ' USA'),
('NEY', 'BEFÄLHAVARE OCH MILITÄRER', ' FRAN'),
('ALBA', 'BEFÄLHAVARE OCH MILITÄRER', ' SPAN'),
('FOCH', 'BEFÄLHAVARE OCH MILITÄRER', ' FRAN'),
('GIAP', 'BEFÄLHAVARE OCH MILITÄRER', ' VIET'),
('HAIG', 'BEFÄLHAVARE OCH MILITÄRER', ' USA')
```

Thanks

Comment: The official SQLite release does not support multi-VALUES insert just yet. But the development branch has been upgraded to have this feature. [http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/eb3b6a0ceb](http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/eb3b6a0ceb) (this comment is for the sake of anyone reading this stackoverflow page later this year or in 2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is use to insert data into the Database

initialization of the database

```
-(id)init{
    if(self=[super init]) {
        documentsDirectory_Statement;
        documentsDirectory=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourApplication.sqlite"];
        self.dbPath=documentsDirectory;
        NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:self.dbPath]) {
            NSString *localDB=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourApplication" ofType:@"sqlite"];
            NSError *err;
            if(![fm copyItemAtPath:localDB toPath:self.dbPath error:&err]){
                NSLog(@"Error in creating DB -> %@",err);
            }
        }

        if(sqlite3_open([self.dbPath UTF8String], &database) !=SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"error while opening database.");
        } else {
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Numbers of Constants

```
#define PUT_Value(_TO_,_FROM_) { \
NSString *str=[dObj valueForKey:_FROM_]; \
if(!str) str=@" "; \
sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,_TO_,[str UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT); \
}

#define PUT_Blob(_TO_,_FROM_) { \
    sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStmt,_TO_,[[dObj valueForKey:_FROM_] bytes],[[dObj valueForKey:_FROM_] length],NULL);\
}

#define PUT_Integer(_TO_,_FROM_) { \
    NSInteger numbr=[[dObj valueForKey:_FROM_] intValue]; \
    sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStmt,_TO_,numbr); \
}


#define PUT_Double(_TO_,_FROM_) { \
CGFloat doubleX=[[dObj valueForKey:_FROM_] floatValue]; \
sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStmt,_TO_,doubleX); \
}


#define PUT_Date(_TO_,_FROM_) { \
sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,_TO_, [[[dObj valueForKey:_FROM_] description] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);\
}


#define GET_Value(_TO_,_FROM_) NSString *_TO_; { \
const unsigned char *c=sqlite3_column_text(compiledStmt,_FROM_); \
_TO_= c ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)c] : @"" ; \
}

#define GET_Double(_TO_,_FROM_) double _TO_;{ \
_TO_=sqlite3_column_double(compiledStmt,_FROM_); \
}

#define GET_Integer(_TO_,_FROM_) NSUInteger _TO_; { \
_TO_ = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStmt,_FROM_); \
}

#define GET_Date(_TO_,_FROM_) { \
_TO_=sqlite3_column_double(compiledStmt, _FROM_)];\
}

#define GET_Blob(_TO_,_FROM_) { \
_TO_=sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStmt, _FROM_) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStmt, _FROM_)];\
}
```

Insert Funcation

```
-(void)insertItem:(NSArray*)arItem{

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
    if(sqlite3_open([self.dbPath UTF8String], &database) ==SQLITE_OK) {


        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", -1, &compiledStmt, NULL);
        sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);

        const char *sqlInsertQry="insert into alarm (id,years,months,days,hours,minutes,seconds,body) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsertQry, -1, &compiledStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ){
            for (NSDictionary *dObj in arItem) {
                PUT_Integer(1,@"id");
                PUT_Integer(2,@"years");
                PUT_Integer(3,@"months");
                PUT_Integer(4,@"days");
                PUT_Integer(5,@"hours");
                PUT_Integer(6,@"minutes");   
                PUT_Integer(7,@"seconds");                
                PUT_Value(8,@"body");                


                NSUInteger err = sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
                if (err != SQLITE_DONE){
                    NSLog(@"error while binding %d %s",err, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }
                sqlite3_reset(compiledStmt);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);     
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Invalid Query");
        }
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "END TRANSACTION", -1, &compiledStmt, NULL);
        sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt); 
        sqlite3_close(database);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error while opening database.");
    }
}
```

Hope this code is helping to implement the database connectivity.

@Samuel

Answer (score 1):

That's possible, but not with the usual comma-separated insert values.

Try this...

```
insert into myTable (col1,col2) 
     select aValue as col1,anotherValue as col2 
     union select moreValue,evenMoreValue 
     union...
```

Yes, it's a little ugly but easy enough to automate the generation of the statement from a set of values. Also, it appears you only need to declare the column names in the first select.

Answer (score -1):

For your above query you have to create array and insert in to sqlite.

Comment: But i have to insert data by executing query in sqlite database manually not programmatically

Comment: which browser you are using to add query